# how to record and generate JVM heap dump of running process till it completes

Tags: java, jvm

Basically, I am running a java process on linux machine and able to capture heap dump of JVM Memory using the following command, but I am thinking it may not be the correct way because the time I have captured heap,may not have the complete and correct object status(they may be still running because process is still running).

So I wanted to know how can I take the heap dump of the complete process execution. Right now I am not getting any out of memory issue but to trouble shoot to find which objects are using higher memory or suspected leaks.

```
jmap <pid> <filepathtogeneratedheap>
```

Comment: If you mean you need a kind of recording of the whole excution I suggest you to use Java Mission Control. It is in bundle with JDK.

Comment: Ok thanks. also, Just want to know if we generate dump in between using Jmap, it won't give correct picture of heap memory object summary isn't it?

Comment: Actually I am running my process on remote JVM on Linux machine , I have only read access on that machine and I don't know on which port the   JVM is running on that machine. How do I use VisualVM or Java Mission Control to record remote process and not on windows?

Comment: you could try [jvm-object-inspector](https://github.com/JigarJoshi/jvm-objects-inspector), it is experimental though and has huge performance penalty

Comment: Dumps with Jmap should give you a correct information about the allocated heap. But you have to do the hard work to correlate each dump to extract trend or evolution.

Comment: To debug a java process remotely you have to know something on JVM launch parameters. But I think your questions should be more specific otherwise it's difficult to give you a "correct" answer.

Comment: Ok thanks all for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, for running process, it is not good idea to generate heap dump. I have solved this problem by letting JVM generating the heap dump when it throws OutOfMemoryError